# Запись контента в переменные в зависимости от названия файла

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Прошу помощи, поскольку нуб в пхп.

Мне нужно спарсить контент из htm файлов, сам парсер готов, но требуется в зависимости от имени файла записать в одну из двух переменных. Имена файлов различаются только тем, что на конце есть 1 - vopros.htm vopros1.htm.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы контент из vopros.htm записался в одну переменную, а vopros1.htm - в другую. Проблема в том, что файлов много.

Comment: @Uchiha1992, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

К примеру,

```
$files = glob($dir . '/vopros*.htm');
```

[glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php)

Comment: проблемы со считыванием файлов нет, мне нужно сделать, чтобы запись была в разные переменные

Comment: Тогда, действительно, file_get_contents.

Comment: и file_get_contents тоже использую с этим проблемы нет, проблема не со считыванием инфы из файла,  с распределением ее по переменным

Comment: Можно использовать массив:

    $contents = array();
    foreach($files as $file){
        $contents[$file] = file_get_contents($file);
    }
    print_r($contents);

Comment: и массив тоже есть,
в общем, вот мой код http://pastebin.com/0NjgqGv4

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)